# What is the elegant way of processing a list of asynchronous events and continuing once they are all complete?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs, subject-observer

I am building an Angular app.  In the constructor of my component, I am initiating a request for several elements from the server, which naturally occur asynchronously.  Those requests are returned to me as `rxjs/Behavior` objects, to which I am subscribed.

What I need to do is continue processing as soon as the last one is back.  But I *NEED* to make sure that they are processed in the order in which they were submitted, not necessarily in the order in which they were returned.

I could create a janky hack to detect when the last one has returned:

```
let counter = 0;
let output = new Array( input.length );
for ( let i = 0 ; i < input.length ; i++ ) {
  counter++;
  fetch( input[i] ).subscribe( 
    result => {
      output[i] = result;
      counter--;
      if ( counter === 0 ) {
        // what to do at the end
      }
    }
  );
}
```

And this works.  But it's ugly, it is not easy to understand, and not what I would call production-ready code.

What is the Angular way of doing something once an array of subjects have all been fulfilled?

Comment: You should not be receiving `Subject`s. If you have stewardship of the API in question, use `.asObservable()` to hide the implementation. If you don't then, I suggest that you find a new library.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `forkJoin`:

```
Observable.forkJoin(...input.map(fetch)) 
 .subscribe(responses => {
    // responses contains the emitted values after completion
    // in the same order as input
  });
```

See [the docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkJoin.html) for more details and some things to watch out for.

As an extended tip for the future, the rxjs website has a pretty good questionnaire that helps you find the operator you are looking for in various situations.